# C equivalent operator creating confusion

Tags: c

**Program 1:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i=55;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",i==55,i=40,i==40,i>=10);
}
```

**Program 2:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    int i = 55;
    if(i == 55) {
        printf("hi");
    }
}
```

First program give output `0 40 0 1` here in the `printf i == 55` and output is 0 and in the second program too `i ==55` and output is hi. why

Comment: you have assignment operation in first printf!!..output of first code is implementation defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first example, the operators are evaluated in reverse order because they are pushed like this on the stack. The evaluation order is implementation specific and not defined by the C standard. So the squence is like this:

1. i=55 initial assignment
2. i>=10  == true             1
3. i==40  == false (It's 55)  0
4. i=40  assignment          40
5. i==55  == false (It's 40)  0

The second example should be obvious.

Answer (score 5):

There's no guarantee about the order in which arguments to a function are evaluated. There's also no sequence point between evaluating the different arguments to the function.

That means your first call gives undefined behavior, because it both uses the existing value of `i` *and* writes a new value to `i` without a sequence point between the two.

In a typical case, however, each argument to a function will be evaluated as a separate expression, with no interleaving between them. In other words, the compiler will impose some order to the evaluation, even though the standard doesn't require it to do so.

In the specific case of a variadic function, the arguments are typically pushed onto the stack from right to left, so the first argument (the format string) will be at the top of the stack. This makes it easy for `printf` to find the format string, and then (based on that) retrieve the rest of the arguments from further down the stack.

If (as is *fairly* typical) the arguments are evaluated immediately prior to being pushed on the stack, this will lead to the arguments being evaluated from right to left as well.

Functions with a fixed number of arguments aren't evaluated from right to left nearly as often, so if (for example) you wrote a small wrapper taking a fixed number of arguments, that then passed those through to `printf`, there's a greater chance that `i` would have the value `55` when the first argument to `printf` is evaluated, so that would produce a 1 instead of a 0.

Note, however, that neither result is guaranteed, nor is *any* meaningful result guaranteed--since you have undefined behavior, *anything* is allowed to happen.

Comment: Arguments are always pushed from right to left. Nothing specisal about prointf or variadic functions.

Comment: @Devolus: I suggest you read about some different calling conventions (what you're claiming is just plain wrong). Just for example, Microsoft's compiler supports cdecl calling convention, which pushes right to left and caller cleans up the stack--but it also supports `stdcall`, `fastcall`, and (in C++) `thiscall`, all of which push arguments left to right, and the callee cleans up the stack.

Comment: @Devolus: Actually, I've simplified a bit, but the basic fact remains: there are calling conventions that push left to right. As far as the C standard cares, either order is completely allowable--as is something completely different, such as having a linked list of heap-allocated activation records, and no stack at all (which is roughly what IBM mainframes use).

Answer (score 3):

The arguments of printf are evaluated from right to left here (this is unspecified behavior, but the behaviour you noticed shows that at least the first argument is evaluated after the second). In your argument list there ist `i=40`, which sets the value to 40. Therefore the first printed argument is false (0).

Comment: Evaluation order is undefined. Mostly depending on the optimization. The values put to the stack is from right to the left.

Comment: To put parameters to the stack is also implementation specific. For example, for x86-64 target, `gcc` uses registers instead of the stack.

Comment: @TrueY then you say it `unspecified behavior` not a 'undefined behaviour'

Comment: @urseit change `implementation specific` to `unspecified behavior` read here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the order in which the arguments to the `printf` function (actually any function) are evaluated, before being passed to the function, is not defined by the C standard.

The problem is not with your understanding of the `==` operator.

**Edit:** Although many authors are pointing out that `printf` typically evaluates its arguments from right-to-left (which I wasn't aware of), I would say it's probably a bad idea to write code that depends on this, as the language does not guarantee it, and it makes the code much less readable.  Nevertheless is is a good factoid to know in case you come across it in the wild.

Answer (score 2):

The function printf evaluates the expressions in implementation specific manner, in this case from right to left. Hence the output:

```
i==55(0),i=40(Assignment),i==40(0),i>=10(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first program: The order of evaluation of the `printf()` arguments is implimentation defined. So this program doesn't give the same result on different implimentation of `printf()` So there is no guarantee  about what the program will result.

It could output `0 40 0 1` as it could output `1 40 1 1` if the order of evaluation is reversed.